# "or" statement pandas python for finding and replacing string does not work

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("scedon_etoimo.csv")

df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

if df[(df['ship_from'].str.contains('<')) | (df['ship_from'].str.contains(' '))]:
  print(df['ship_from'])
```

In the csv I have the last column which contains either string or NaN or < 
 Name_of_a_country / strong> (my purpose is to replace those with another string). But when I run it to see if my statement works, I get the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I have already checked this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Any help?

Comment: `df['ship_from'].str.contains("<|' '")`

Comment: You can't use `if` with dataframes as the error tells you, because they have more than value and python does not how to assess its truthfulness. You can call `len()` on your `df[(df['ship_from'].str.contains('<')) | (df['ship_from'].str.contains(' '))]` and check if it has elements inside.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the question you linked? If you did, why are you trying to use a `pandas.DataFrame` as a boolean condition?